# getting all the methods in a file

Tags: php, regex, lithium

I am trying to find a best way to get all the private, public, static, protected methods in a file.... what would be the best way to do it. currently when I do file_get_contents it dumps the whole file but I need some kind of regex that will give me methods only

```
$filecontent = file_get_contents($fn->getPath()."/".$fn->getFilename());
```

I am not sure if I can use this

```
preg_match("/private function | protected function | public function | public static function/") etc etc
```

if there is a better way I would like to know about that as well

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to use reflection for this? http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: Reading the documentation is always a great idea=)

Comment: well this cant be used....It wouldnt find the class as its not included

Comment: What's stopping you from including it. Reflection is probably the cleanest way to do this

Comment: curious to know what is the "orignal" use case or need!

Answer (score 3):

Use reflection, assuming your path is PSR-0 you can do something along the lines:

```
<?php

$document_root = "/document/root";

$file = "{$document_root}/PSR/Compatible/Path/ClassName.php";

$class = str_replace(
  array($document_root, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ".php"),
  array("", "\\", ""),
  $file
);

$reflector = new \ReflectionClass($class);

var_dump($reflector->getMethods());

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this doesnt work...gives me syntax error for [ in str_replace(
  [ $document_root,

Comment: Use `array()` syntax if your PHP version is too old.